# OpenDKIM milter not signing relayed mail

Tags: email, postfix, opendkim

I'm using OpenDKIM to sign mail on my Postfix server.  It works as intended when sending with SMTPS from it's origin domain (let's say `example.com`).  However, mail set out from SMTP clients on the LAN are not being signed.  Said clients do not have from the same origin domain (for example `client1.lan`), but are translated with `smtp_generic_maps` to the same origin (specifically `client1@example.com`).  Ideally, I want to sign that outgoing mail.

In /etc/postfix/main.cf I have:

```
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

In /etc/opendkim.conf I have:

```
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
```

In /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts I have:

```
::1
127.0.0.1
localhost
ip6-localhost
ip6-loopback
mail
10.0.0.0/24
*.lan
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postfix make sure `/etc/postfix/main.conf` contains:

```
milter_mail_macros = i {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_authen} {auth_type}
```

This will ensure that mail coming from authenticated users will be signed by OpenDKIM.  As per documentation:

> A  message will be verified unless it conforms to the signing criteria, which are: (1) the domain on the From: address (if present) must be listed by the -d command line  switch  or the  Domain  configuration file setting, and (2) **(a) the client connecting to the MTA must have authenticated**, or (b) the client connecting to the MTA must be  listed  in  the  file referenced  by the InternalHosts configuration file setting (or be in the default list for that option), or (c) the client must be connected to a  daemon  port  named  by  the  MTAs configuration  file  setting, or (d) the MTA must have set one or more macros matching the criteria set by the MacroList configuration file setting.
>
> For (a) above, the test is whether or not the MTA macro "{auth_type}" is set and  contains any  non-empty  value.  This means the MTA must pass the value of that macro to the filter before or during the end-of-header (EOH) phase in order for its value to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

If they are to be relayed and signed to other domains (based on the `From:` header), then you'll have to map these other domains with the `SigningTable` configuration at opendkim, you may even assign different keys and selectors by matching them at the `KeyTable` — both point to different mapping files.

I had a similar problem, but I could debug it by looking at the mail headers — there you'll find the exact hostname and IP address the relayed server is using, for example:

```
Received: from client1.lan (client1.localdomain [10.0.0.2]) by example.com 
          (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 71B8D10C1A68 for <client1@example.com>;
          Sun, 12 Feb 2017 13:19:33 +0000 (UTC)
```

Then you can check if the relayed server is using the internal network, which hostname it's using and to what domain it intends to send e-mail from.

Comment: As I suspected.  Now they get signed, but the signature is wrong because the header was modified after signing.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue: mail being sent from remote host didn't get signed.

The solution was simple: just to add the IP of a remote sender to **/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts**